# Print out multiple Divs in different pages

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to print out different divs in different pages, and it's only printing the first div.

The divs are built in a for loop and all have the same id, I've added the page-break-after: always; to the css and it didn't work.

```
<?php

for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
    echo "<div id='divPrint'><h4>This Is a Page<h4></div>";
}

?>


<input type="button" onClick="javascript:CallPrint('divPrint')">

<script>
function CallPrint(strid)
{
var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=800,height=600');
WinPrint.document.open();
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
}

<script>
```

All the 10 divs need to be in different pages.

Comment: HTML elements are **never** meant to have the same `id`. Ids, in fact, are meant to be **unique**. Either use a class to get all of them, either make a unique ID by taking advantage of the index: `'divPrint_$x'`.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Also if you expect your button to print ALL the divs on a page each, you need to do more CSS formatting with page-break